# How can I add a blur effect like in this Pinterest Login Screen in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am creating a login screen using Flutter and want this type of effect takes place when the Images and White Background connect.[Pinterest Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvdzX.jpg)

I am a newbie and haven't figured out the package yet.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `ShaderMask()`

```
ShaderMask(
  shaderCallback: (rect) {
    return LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      colors: [Colors.black, Colors.transparent],
    ).createShader(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height));
  },
  blendMode: BlendMode.dstIn,
  child: Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/500?image=9'),
  ),
),
```

[image]